# Calendar table in power bi

Tags: calendar, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to use calendar table for creating fiscal year

i tried this but this shows red mark under the dates

```
Calendar = ADDCOLUMNS(CALENDAR (DATE("1-Jul-2015"), DATE("30-Jun-2017")),
"Year",YEAR([Date]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DATE function takes three arguments, like this:

```
DATE(<year>, <month>, <day>)
```

So your table should be:

```
Calendar = ADDCOLUMNS(
  CALENDAR(
    DATE(2015, 7, 1),
    DATE(2017, 6, 30)
  ),
  "Year", YEAR([Date])
)
```

Here is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/date-function-dax

Comment: hi one problem is i also get time on date column where as i want only date

Comment: Just change the type in the frontend under the modelling tab > Format > Date Time > yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to a date than hard copy a date value. To cover all dates, it is better to use MIN and MAX of dates from your fact table and base your calendar on them:
Here is a good video on this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oq5WOmo94_Q